# Fragment error in Android: binary XML file inflate exception

Tags: android, android-fragments

I just want to use simple fragment, but it shows a problem I could not figure out.

I have been trying it for a long time. Please help me. It gives the following error:

> android.view.inflateException: Binary xml file line #11 error

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.myfragmentqadvance;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Fragment1.Communicator {
    Fragment1 f1;
    Fragment2 f2;
    FragmentManager manager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        manager= getFragmentManager();
        f1=(Fragment1) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
        f1.setCommunicator(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void respond(int index) {
        f2=(Fragment2) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        if(f2!=null & f2.isVisible()){
            f2.changedData(index);
        }else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,AnotherAcitivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("index", index);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity.main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.example.myfragmentqadvance.Fragment1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment1.java**

```
package com.example.myfragmentqadvance;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {
    ListView list;
    Communicator communicator;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment1, container, false);
        list=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),     R.array.chapter, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }



    public void setCommunicator(Communicator communicator) {
        this.communicator = communicator;
    }

    public interface Communicator{
        public void respond(int index);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int i, long arg3) {
        communicator.respond(i);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfragmentqadvance"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfragmentqadvance.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfragmentqadvance.Fragment1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment1" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfragmentqadvance.Fragment2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfragmentqadvance.AnotherAcitivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_another_acitivity" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**Logcat** if it helps

```
05-27 06:56:51.768: D/dalvikvm(857): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 39K, 6% free 2558K/2720K, paused 35ms, total 38ms

05-27 06:56:51.778: I/dalvikvm-heap(857): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.220MB for 635812-byte allocation

05-27 06:56:51.828: D/dalvikvm(857): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3177K/3344K, paused 47ms, total 47ms

05-27 06:56:51.879: D/dalvikvm(857): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3179K/3344K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 57ms

05-27 06:56:51.918: D/AndroidRuntime(857): Shutting down VM

05-27 06:56:51.918: W/dalvikvm(857): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)

05-27 06:56:51.938: E/AndroidRuntime(857): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

05-27 06:56:51.938: E/AndroidRuntime(857): java.lang.RuntimeException:     Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{com.example.myfragmentqadvance/com.example.
                   myfragmentqadvance.MainActivity}:     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
05-27 06:56:51.938: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)

05-27 06:56:51.938: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

05-27 06:56:51.938: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

05-27 06:56:51.938: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)

05-27 06:56:51.938: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

05-27 06:56:51.938: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

05-27 06:56:51.938: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

05-27 06:56:51.938: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

05-27 06:56:51.938: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

05-27 06:56:51.938: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

05-27 06:56:51.938: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

05-27 06:56:51.938: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

05-27 06:56:51.938: E/AndroidRuntime(857): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment

05-27 06:56:51.938: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)

05-27 06:56:51.938: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
```

Comment: can you add the crash report aswell?

Comment: import R ? stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: avoid having the activity register itself as the fragments interface by calling `setCommunicator`, and instead have the fragment check the Activity in its `onAttach`. In this scenario you should be ok, but if you use a transaction to add the fragment, after a configuration change, it is easy to lose the callback, or leak the old instance of the activity

Answer (score 0):

May be you have some small errors in the .xml files. please check those files once.

Solution :

You can add the fragment to your relative layout, but to do that properly you'll need to assign it appropriate layout parameters so that it can be placed. It would be easier to just create a FrameLayout within the relative layout that wraps its contents, and then add the fragment there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/FragmentContainer"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/B1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.FragmentContainer, fragment);
```

No need to declare `fragments` in Manifest file as activity

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfragmentqadvance.Fragment1"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment1" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfragmentqadvance.Fragment2"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment2" >
</activity>
```

remove this part of code. not require.

Answer (score 0):

*fragment* in your activity_main.xml is not valid, also it seems you want to have Fragment1. Change fragment to com.example.myfragmentqadvance.Fragment1

Answer (score 0):

I got the soln. when i use onActivityCreated it works...

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment1, container, false); 
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    list=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),     R.array.chapter, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

it works fine but gives null pointer exeption